# Optimizing table for performance

Tags: mysql, queue, innodb, database-performance

I have 2 tables for a simple parser I use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parsers` (
  `parser_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_used` datetime NOT NULL,
  `engine_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notice` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parser_id`),
  KEY `last_used_2` (`last_used`,`parser_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=167541 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `engines` (
  `engine_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `in_use` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_used` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`engine_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1201 ;
```

Which is basically a parser queue. The following query assigns a job to a parser

```
UPDATE parsers SET job_id = '$job_id', last_used = NOW() WHERE job_id IS NULL AND status = 1 AND engine_id IN(SELECT engine_id FROM engines WHERE in_use = 0) ORDER BY last_used ASC
```

The assigned job then gets picked up for further processing:

```
SELECT * FROM parsers WHERE job_id = '$job_id'
```

My problem is that the UPDATE query gets very slow when several parsers are active on the query, the query sometimes takes 10 seconds to execute which is unacceptable as it slows down everything a lot.

The EXPLAIN shows me `using where;using filesort` and I think the flaw is in the `using filesort`.

I think adding indexes can solve this and speed up the query.

I tried adding `ALTER TABLE parsers ADD INDEX(last_used,parser_id)` which improved performance for a while and which also let the `using filesort` go away but as I checked again today the `using filesort` was back and the performance was as bad as before.
Was that index even correct? How can I speed the table up?

Comment: Your `engine_id IN(SELECT engine_id FROM engines WHERE in_use = 0)` is going to be a little inefficient, you should probably do an inner join, other than that adding an index to the status_id and job_id of your parser, which should help considerably.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for indexes is you need them to cover your `WHERE` conditions, and if it's important, include anything relevant to `ORDER` afterwards.

In your case you need an index that covers `parser_id` since that's the only thing present in the query. An index on `last_used,parser_id` is useless for this query.

As a note, if you're trying to build a job queue in MySQL and need maximum performance you're going to be fighting an uphill battle. Better options include [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) as a queue solution, or [Redis](http://redis.io/) as a high-speed database.